# Problem with Mesh in Contour Plot

Tags: plotting, mesh

So I was using ContourPlot to plot an equation and I want to highlight the sampling points of the contour plot. So as written in the Mathematica documentation, I tried using `Mesh -> All` but I get nothing. I am new to Mathematica so it'll be nice if someone helps me out with this. Thanks.

My Code:

```
ContourPlot[(1.5303030303030298 + 2/x) x^0.5665236051502147 - (
   3.03030303030303 + y/2)/y^0.14163090128755368` == 0, {x, 0.5, 
  1.5}, {y, 0.0001, 1.9999}, Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red] , MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 ContourStyle -> Black]
```

Comment: From the documentation of [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) you can see that when you plot an equation, you will get *LINES* that satisfy said equation. What mesh?

Comment: Try: Mesh -> Full

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks!